# Add formula to a cell outside the selection set using 'For Each' loop

Tags: vba, excel

A selection box can occur anywhere below the second line beneath my header row.  I need to insert the number of valid rows within the selection range and then afterward add a formula to each cell in column 102 for the newly inserted rows.  I am not all that familiar with the 'For Each' loop method but I do know I am not trying to add the formula to each cell of the selection, only in column 102. Example:

- header row is row 10
- cells B13 to C16 are selected when the code executes
- cell in row 13 column 102 gets the formula "=sum(Q13:t13)"
- cell in row 14 column 102 gets the formula "=sum(q14:t14)"
- cell in row 15 column 102 gets the formula "=sum(q15:t15)"
- cell in row 16 column 102 gets the formula "=sum(q16:t16)"

I have not gotten around to adjusting my code for the formula yet, but that will be my next step.  Right now the problem I have is that I can only place the formula in the last row in column 102, not every row in 102.

```
Private Sub AddRows()
    Dim HeaderRow as Integer

    HeaderRow=10 'define the header row

    With Selection
        If .Row > HeaderRow + 1 Then 'use only rows that are after the header row
            .EntireRow.Insert        'insert the rows 
            For Each Row In Selection.Rows
                .Cells(Row, 102).Value = "=sum($F19:$CW19)" '19 needs to match row number
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You should definitely add an `OPTION EXPLICIT` at the top of your modules, and declare your variables. And using `row` as a variable name is really looking for trouble.

Comment: row was not supposed to be a variable.  I thought it was a function like .value or .formula.  As stated earlier I am not that familiar with how to use the FOR EACH method of programming. Also not sure how to use the "option explicit and where is goes"

Comment: then google for "option explicit", and USE IT. And YES, you definitely use `row` as an object  variable which you should not. Replace it with `r` for more clarity. After you add the option explicit, compile. One should always compile his code.

Comment: well since I was not wanting to use row as a variable, how do you get the formula to be placed in the rows equal to the rows of the selected range which wont include column 102?

Comment: did you look at my edit ?

Comment: Did not see the Edit down below, looking at it now.  Without testing it I assume is pastes the formula into any blank cells between row 1 and the last row as however I have defined last row.  I will be testing shortly and that would do away with the whole for each loop thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect case for R1C1 type formula. Something like

```
.Cells(Row, 102).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC6:RC101)"
```

If you really want the value instead of the formula, you can add one line:

```
.Cells(Row, 102).Value = .Cells(Row, 102).Value
```

---

### EDIT

You could add the formula at once to column 102 after all your inserts:

```
With Range("CX1:CX" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC6:RC101)"
End With
```

Comment: Similar results to what DragonSamu had  your solution is a little cleaner.  However that is not the focus of my question.  that is the next step.  The current question is how do I get it to add the formula to each cell in column 102.  That is the part that is not working.  I only now just discovered that I am currently doing some sort of relative column positioning instead of absolute positioning too.

Comment: The "edit" allows me to do what I was asking, as well as the next step.  Thank you very much for the assistance with this issue.  This works really great when adding rows to the middle of my table.  Is there a way to count the number of rows in a selection?  I am just thinking of the case where I am adding rows to the bottom of my table and I need to increase the lastrow count by the number of rows added.

Comment: Fine. Then you should now "Accept" my answer...  and always use `Option Explicit` ;-)

Comment: I did, however due to my low rating it said something about not being able to change publicly viewed vote or something to that effect, but I did hit the up arrow. Dang just saw the check mark...how did I miss that before.